# prefix to infix conversion using singly linked list handling double digit and negative digits in C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list, prefix, infix-notation, negative-integer

I have been trying a lot but I cannot come up with an algorithm to convert prefix to Infix using singly linked list. Also I have to deal with integers -99 to 99. Can anyone at least provide me an algorithm to for this. Thank you very much!!
I am coding in C

Comment: *"I have been trying a lot"* - Then you'll have *something* to show for it, however minuscule. Please post it in your question.

Comment: Prefix notation can be easily implemented using stacks. Single-linked list are very good as stacks. Think a little about that, preferably using pen and paper, while you search the Internet for any of the thousands of examples that are available.